# i don't know why 'runtime error' message occurs

Tags: java

These are my code. I practice algorithm about 'The little prince'. The algorithm 's contents are that if you input starting point and destination point, you should find how many you cross the planet's range. I submitted my code below to receive score. But I received 'runtime error' message. I couldn't find the solution. Please advise about my code. I think answer itself about algorithm is correct.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Planet
{
    int cx;
    int cy;
    int r;
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCase=Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());//input test case
        int answer[]=new int[testCase];
        String str[]=scanner.nextLine().split(" ");//input start and dest point
        int x1=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
        int y1=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
        int x2=Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
        int y2=Integer.parseInt(str[3]);
        if(x1!=y1&&x2!=y2)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<testCase;i++)
            {               
                int count=0;
                int planetNum=Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());//input planet counts
                LinkedList<Planet> planetList=new LinkedList<>();
                for(int j=0;j<planetNum;j++)
                {
                    String inputPlanet[]=scanner.nextLine().split(" ");//each planet's (x,y) and radius
                    Planet planet=new Planet();
                    planet.cx=Integer.parseInt(inputPlanet[0]);
                    planet.cy=Integer.parseInt(inputPlanet[1]);
                    planet.r=Integer.parseInt(inputPlanet[2]);
                    planetList.add(planet);
                }
                for(int j=0;j<planetList.size();j++)
                {
                    double startDistance=Math.sqrt((planetList.get(j).cx-x1)*(planetList.get(j).cx-x1)
                            +(planetList.get(j).cy-y1)*(planetList.get(j).cy-y1));
                    double destDistance=Math.sqrt((planetList.get(j).cx-x2)*(planetList.get(j).cx-x2)
                            +(planetList.get(j).cy-y2)*(planetList.get(j).cy-y2));

                    if(startDistance<planetList.get(j).r||destDistance<planetList.get(j).r)
                        count++;
                }   
                answer[i]=count;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<testCase;i++)
                answer[i]=0;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<testCase;i++)
            System.out.println(answer[i]);

    }
}
```

*input*

---

2

-5 1 12 1

7

1 1 8

-3 -1 1

2 2 2

5 5 1

-4 5 1

12 1 1

12 1 2

1

0 0 2

*output*

---

3

0

Comment: No error message or line number that hints you in the right direction?

Comment: where is the runtime error?

Comment: apart from the lack or error message, you need to check the number of elements in the array after splitting it otherwise you are going to get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: i'm so sorry about my shortage. this is first time that i post question. when i compiled in eclipse, i didn't receive the error message.

Answer (score 1):

**Where is your problem?** I copied your code. Changed scanner.nextLine() to inputArray[inputIndex++] and filled it (inputArray) with your displayed input. I received zero exceptions. Without the exception-  it's wasting our time. We still want to help. **Show us your Exception with stacktrace.**

```
class Planet // I put everything under the Planet class.
{
    int cx;
    int cy;
    int r;

    // These two simulate user input
    static int inputIndex = 0;
    static String[] inputArray =  {  
       "2",
       "-5 1 12 1",
       "7",
       "1 1 8",
       "-3 -1 1",
       "2 2 2",
       "5 5 1",
       "-4 5 1",
       "12 1 1",
       "12 1 2",
       "1",
       "0 0 2"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int testCase=Integer.parseInt(inputArray[inputIndex++]);//input test case
    int answer[]=new int[testCase];
    String str[]=inputArray[inputIndex++].split(" ");//input start and dest point
    int x1=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
    int y1=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
    int x2=Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
    int y2=Integer.parseInt(str[3]);
    if(x1!=y1&&x2!=y2)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<testCase;i++)
        {               
            int count=0;
            int planetNum=Integer.parseInt(inputArray[inputIndex++]);//input planet counts
            LinkedList<Planet> planetList=new LinkedList<>();
            for(int j=0;j<planetNum;j++)
            {
                String inputPlanet[]=inputArray[inputIndex++].split(" ");//each planet's (x,y) and radius
                Planet planet=new Planet();
                planet.cx=Integer.parseInt(inputPlanet[0]);
                planet.cy=Integer.parseInt(inputPlanet[1]);
                planet.r=Integer.parseInt(inputPlanet[2]);
                planetList.add(planet);
            }
            for(int j=0;j<planetList.size();j++)
            {
                double startDistance=Math.sqrt((planetList.get(j).cx-x1)*(planetList.get(j).cx-x1)
                        +(planetList.get(j).cy-y1)*(planetList.get(j).cy-y1));
                double destDistance=Math.sqrt((planetList.get(j).cx-x2)*(planetList.get(j).cx-x2)
                        +(planetList.get(j).cy-y2)*(planetList.get(j).cy-y2));

                if(startDistance<planetList.get(j).r||destDistance<planetList.get(j).r)
                    count++;
            }   
            answer[i]=count;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<testCase;i++)
            answer[i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<testCase;i++)
        System.out.println(answer[i]);

}
}
```

Comment: plus 1 for attempt.

Comment: I'm so sorry. This is first time that i post question. Please forgive my shortage. I don't have exception. When i compiled my code in eclipse, it didn't have a problem. I even could get the correct answer. However, when i submit my code to algorithm site, it sends the message 'runtime error' to me.

Comment: @박형준 PLEASE Don't worry about a "poor question". We're trying to help. We just need all the information to help you properly. The problem appears to be your algorithm web site. It's expecting something you aren't supplying.